# Creating a dictionary from a nested dictionary only if a parameter is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

How can you use dictionary comprehension to iterate over a nested dictionary within a dictionary, For example lets say I have the dictionary:

```
dict = { 0: { "id":"2131224", "name":"Sara",},1: {"id":"4156234","name":"John"}}
```

I want to know if I can make a dictionary from this parent dictionary if the inner keys are equal to some specific string and the value corresponding to that string.
I tried using dict.items() but that doesn't move into the inner dictionaries, the desired output Im wanting looks like this

```
separated = [{"name":"Sara"},{"name":"John"}]
```

Comment: The inner key is common in all the inner dictionaries and I want to separate them out from the rest, the data is imported from a websocket and it was in list format so I couldnt find a better way to iterate over it except to convert it to a dictionary

Comment: I just updated it

Comment: **Note**: never shadow built-ins, use `d`, `dict_` or something descriptive for your variable name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "if a parameter is True". But you can use a list comprehension for your desired result:

```
d = {0: { "id":"2131224", "name":"Sara",}, 1: {"id":"4156234","name":"John"}}

res = [{'name': v['name']} for v in d.values()]

[{'name': 'Sara'}, {'name': 'John'}]
```

Comment: Thanks it works, also how would this scale to add more parameters, like if the original nested dictionaries also had key: value pairs for job: Yes/No, how would I make a list of people for whom the job parameter is Yes or No

Comment: @Afzal, SO isn't a forum. If you have a new question, please ask [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Afzal, No problem. If this solves the problem in your question you should accept it (green tick on left) so other users know.